# How to activate hidden features using Powershell

Tags: powershell, features, hidden

I want to activate site scoped and web scoped hidden features using Powershell Command. What will be the command?

Comment: There must be a `Hidden` attribute on the feature element in PowerShell. Mb this link can help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543162(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To just activate the feature use the following command:

```
Enable-SPFeature –Identity <<FeatureID>> –url http://myspsite/
```

To find the FeatureID use the following for hidden features:

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Hidden -eq $true -and $_.Scope -eq “WEB”} | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select DisplayName, Id
```

Comment: if i want to hide again, then what will be the command?

Comment: Feature will remain hidden, you just activated it. To deactivate it use Disable-SPFeature.